# EOF about spec = torch.load(spec_filename)

Tags: python, pickle

I have the same problem as follows:

```
spec = torch.load(spec_filename)
magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
```

> EOFError: Ran out of input

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please post the full error output rather than just the messsge.